# How to make my application support ads?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iad

I want to place ads in my application. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options, like AdMob or Google Ads. However, Apple provides the iAd framework, which makes it easy to add ads to your app. I suggest looking at the [iAd framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009705). The basic process is as follows:

1. Create an iAd banner.
2. Set the banner's delegate.
3. Add the ad view to your view.

You also need to set up iAd in your developer account, but that only affects revenue, not the programming and testing aspect of things.

Answer (score 1):

This might be help you.

first one is contain an example of iphone ad adding while second one is for ipad.

[link1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app)

[link2](http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/)

Answer (score 1):

I've done well with [MobPartner](http://web.mobpartner.com). It's just a matter of putting a small banner on a button and linking the button to the ad link they give you.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://advertising.apple.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/). It supports multiple ad networks like AdMob, iAd etc.

The basic idea is that you can switch ad network through a website client(adwhirl.com), instead of reprogramming your app each time.

Instructions in how to set up adwhirl on your iPhone: [iOS SDK Setup](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html).